# Getting last day of each month from given list in java

Tags: java, list, date

Have a list of Dates as below:(DD-MM-YYYY)

```
30-09-2017
22-09-2017
15-09-2017
30-08-2017
22-08-2017
15-07-2017
30-07-2017
22-06-2017
15-06-2017
30-05-2017
22-05-2017
15-05-2017
```

From the above list, has to fetch last day of for last three months. After processing above list output must be like below:

```
30-09-2017
30-08-2017
30-07-2017
```

Need help in java code, if you have already code to achieve this then I am very happy.

Comment: is it a String or Date object ?

Comment: Does every day occcur once or is it possible that one day appears in that list multiple times?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to know that SO is no *code writing service*, we won't give you a solution for a pure *requirement dump*. So please try it yourself and callback if you got stuck, then we help to solve your specific problem. Or alternatively, if you are just seeking for a rough outline, then please clearly state so.

Comment: Seriously, if you google for "java get last day month" you'll find hundreds of examples. Haven't you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Parse each String as a `LocalDate` using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`. From that, get a `YearMonth`.

Make a `Map` using the `YearMonth` as key, and a `SortedSet` as the value. Add each `LocalDate` to the `SortedSet` for its appropriate `YearMonth`.

When done adding, look at each `SortedSet`, extracting its last  element for the latest date used in that month. Add each last date to a `List`. When done adding, sort that `List`.

Voilà!

Answer (score 1):

I'd stream the list, and parse each string to the appropriate `YearMonth`. You can then take the distinct last three and convert them back to strings:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
List<String> lastDays =
    dates.stream()
         .map(d -> YearMonth.parse(d, formatter))
         .distinct()
         .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
         .limit(3)
         .map(m -> m.atEndOfMonth().toString())
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```